# How to connect to postgresql 11 just installed on ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql

In the windows Linux Subsystem, I installed ubuntu 18.04

In there, I installed postgresql 11 using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-11`

I got this back

`Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log`

When I run "psql", I get the error

> psql: could not connect to server: **No such file or directory**
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Then I tried to specify a folder, like this

```
psql -h /var/lib/postgresql/11/main
```

and I get this error...

> psql: could not connect to server: **Permission denied**
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/lib/postgresql/11/main/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `Status` =`down` you want `Status`=`online`. When it's down, the instance may be started with `pg_ctlcluster 11 main start`. `apt-get install` does it by default normally but maybe it encountered an error.

Comment: According to the documentation, I should start the server using `postgres -D ...` but postgres is not found...
`whereis postgres` only reports the man pages...
Bizarre?

Comment: That's just one way of starting the server, when you want to ignore the infrastructure brought by the package and do all by yourself. The doc you want is more like this one: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html

Comment: Silly me, I had missed an instruction

`/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -l logfile start`

But now I get "waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: 1: cannot create logfile: Permission denied" and the log file exists but is empty...

Comment: Looks like I should have replaced "logfile" by the actual name of that logfile: "/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log"

Now, I get something meaningful in that logfile: "postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

I had missed an instruction to start the server...

It finally started with the following instruction

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /etc/postgresql/11/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log start
```

Comment: Indeed, actually silly that the installation says this `usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -l logfile start` instead of the default `/var/log/postgresql/...` location for the logfile.